# Multi-Line TextView, but wrap second line

Tags: android, textview, android-linearlayout, android-custom-view, multiline

I have a brain picking problem that I am trying to solve for smart wrapping for TextView in Android. I have a LinearLayout (horizontal) that consists of TextView1, TextView2 and an ImageView. TextView1 can have long text or short text. For short text everything looks pretty neat and as expected. Like this -

[image]

Now the problem occurs when the text in TextView1 gets longer. Since maxLines for TextView1 is 2, it looks something like this

[image]

This is not an ideal experience because at many occasions there is a lot of white space text just lingering around in second line.

My ideal experience that I want is something like this -

[image]

Any ideas on how I can achieve this type of behavior? I have not written any code yet, because im not even sure how to go about doing it. Any help and pointers will greatly be appreciated. Hoping to get some answers from you all experts.

Edit 1: Adding screenshot based on Gavin's Flexbox suggestion
[image]

Comment: May I see code in .xml?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an ideal case for `FlexboxLayout`. It acts like a `LinearLayout` but then wraps when it hits the end of a line.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Gavin. I tried it, although still not what I want. Attached screenshot above as an Edit1

Comment: I see. Perhaps you can just ellipsize a `TextView` if it requires more than one line? Because `Views` in Android have to be rectangular, so accomplishing exactly what you want would mean measuring the available space and somehow breaking one `TextView` up into multiple `TextViews`.

Comment: Yea, that's what I was thinking. May be i'll have to hack it around that way. :/

Comment: Or perhaps one custom `View` would be easier.

Comment: Hmmm, ill have to brainstorm how ill build that. Just custom view.